CFour: EOM-CCSD calculation produces different transition dipoles when requesting different computational point group symmetries
I am interested in the EOM-CCSD excitation energies and transition dipole moments for the first A_g state of DyO2++, a linear tri-atomic with D_{inf h} symmetry. Running the following calculation in CFour, where I explicitly request C2v to be used as the computational point group (SUBGROUP = 5, per the manual)
Excited states of DyO2++
Dy
O 1 RDyO
X 1 RX 2 A90
O 1 RDyO 3 A90 2 D180

RDyO =   1.670079520275294
RX   =   1.
A90  =  90.
D180 = 180.

*ACES2(CHARGE = 2
         CALC = CCSD
        BASIS = SPECIAL
       EXCITE = EOMEE
     SUBGROUP = 5
   ESTATE_SYM = 1/0/0/0
  ESTATE_PROP = 1
 ESTATE_TRANS = 1
     SCF_CONV = 11
      CC_CONV = 10
  ESTATE_CONV = 9
   RELATIVITY = X2C1E
       DROPMO = 1>16)

Dy:cc-pwCVDZ-X2C
O:cc-pVDZ
O:cc-pVDZ

produces the exact same (within the thresholds I've requested):

SCF energies
CCSD correlation energies
EOMEE-CCSD total energies
Largest elements of the left transition density

as running the same calculation on D2h (by omitting the SUBGROUP keyword and specifying the ESTATE_SYM within D2h):
Excited states of DyO2++
Dy
O 1 RDyO
X 1 RX 2 A90
O 1 RDyO 3 A90 2 D180

RDyO =   1.670079520275294
RX   =   1.
A90  =  90.
D180 = 180.

*ACES2(CHARGE = 2
         CALC = CCSD
        BASIS = SPECIAL
       EXCITE = EOMEE
   ESTATE_SYM = 1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0
  ESTATE_PROP = 1
 ESTATE_TRANS = 1
     SCF_CONV = 11
      CC_CONV = 10
  ESTATE_CONV = 9
   RELATIVITY = X2C1E
       DROPMO = 1>16)

Dy:cc-pwCVDZ-X2C
O:cc-pVDZ
O:cc-pVDZ

However, I get vastly different transition dipoles. For C2V:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 X             Y             Z
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Right Transition Moment    0.03906942   -0.12076371    0.15508001
  Left Transition Moment     0.16140459    0.22243866    0.58353040
  Dipole Strength            0.00630598   -0.02686252    0.09049390
  Oscillator Strength        0.00040055   -0.00170628    0.00574809

For D2h:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 X             Y             Z
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Right Transition Moment   -0.02364990   -0.04042474   -1.34195104
  Left Transition Moment     0.04247352    0.31827753   -3.39360554
  Dipole Strength           -0.00100449   -0.01286629    4.55405247
  Oscillator Strength       -0.00006380   -0.00081725    0.28926929

Just to check, I calculated the first excited state in each symmetry for both C2v and D2h. It seems to happen in general - there is a state in C2v that matches the EOM-CCSD energy in D2h, but the transition dipole is always different...
Does anyone have an idea as to what could be going on?
